# iOS7 NSJSONSerialization - how to drill down multiple levels

Tags: json, ios7, nsjsonserialization

I'm trying to read data from weather underground via their JSON API. I'm able to read *[conditions](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=data/conditions)* data which looks like this:

> weatherReturn = {
>       "current_observation" =     {
>           UV = 1;
>           "dewpoint_c" = 2;
>           "dewpoint_f" = 35;
>           "dewpoint_string" = "35 F (2 C)";
>           "display_location" =         {
>               city = Chicago;
>               country = US; ...

Now, I'm trying to read JSON data from the *[forecast](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=data/forecast)* data which looks like this:

> forecast =     {
>           simpleforecast =         {
>               forecastday =             (
>                                   {
>                       avehumidity = 45;
>                       avewind =                     {
>                           degrees = 141;
>                           dir = SE;
>                           kph = 14;
>                           mph = 9;
>                       };
>                       conditions = Clear;
>                       date =                     {
>                           ampm = PM;
>                           day = 19;

and my code is returning null for the attributes I'm trying to pick up.

Since *forecast* has more layers to the JSON data than conditions, I'm trying a new method which is returning the nulls. Also, I noticed there is a left paren after forecast_day for the forecast data.

The code I'm trying is below:

```
urlNSString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.wunderground.com/api/%@/forecast/q/Chicago.json",
             kWeatherAPIKey];
NSURL *url          = [NSURL URLWithString:urlNSString];

NSData *weatherCall = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];    

id weatherReturn = [NSJSONSerialization weatherCall options:0 error:&error];

NSMutableDictionary *response = [[[weatherReturn valueForKey:@"forecast"] objectAtIndex:0]mutableCopy];
NSString *parma = [response valueForKey:@"avehumidity"];
NSString *parmb = [response valueForKey:@"pretty"];
NSString *parmc = [response valueForKey:@"ampm"];

NSLog(@"parms are %@%@%@",parma,parmb,parmc);
```

When I run with this code I get this error on the NSMutableDictionary statement:
[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9847fa0
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9847fa0'

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: `weatherReturn` isn't a `NSArray`. Remove the `objectAtIndex:` method from getting `response`.

Comment: I tried two approaches and still received nulls:    // NSMutableDictionary *response = [[weatherReturn valueForKey:@"forecast"] mutableCopy];

   // NSMutableDictionary *response = [[[weatherReturn valueForKey:@"forecast"] objectAtIndex:0]mutableCopy]; Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response is not a simple NSDictionary object. It is a dictionary of arrays and dictionaries that may contain other arrays and dictionaries etc.

You have to know what is the structure of your response (for example by NSLogging it).

Try: `NSLog(@"%@", weatherReturn);`

`{...}` means a `NSDictionary` object.

 `(...)` means a `NSArray` object

I changed your code to prove that the params you're looking for are not `nil`.

```c
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    NSString *urlNSString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.wunderground.com/api/%@/forecast/q/Chicago.json",kWeatherAPIKey];
    NSURL *url          = [NSURL URLWithString:urlNSString];

    NSData *weatherCall = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSError *error;
    id weatherReturn = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:weatherCall options:0 error:&error];

    NSLog(@"%@", weatherReturn);

    id forecast = [weatherReturn valueForKey:@"forecast"];
    id simpleforecast = [forecast valueForKey:@"simpleforecast"];
    id forecastday = [simpleforecast valueForKey:@"forecastday"];

    id firstPartOfDailyForecast = [forecastday firstObject];

    id avehumidity = [firstPartOfDailyForecast valueForKey:@"avehumidity"];

    id date = [firstPartOfDailyForecast valueForKey:@"date"];

    id pretty = [date valueForKey:@"pretty"];
    id ampm = [date valueForKey:@"ampm"];


    NSLog(@"Ave:%@\nPretty:%@\nAM/PM:%@", avehumidity, pretty, ampm);
}
```

**IMPORTANT**

I'm not calling `valueForKey:` method on weatherReturn all the time, but i'm getting deeper and deeper inside the response structure.

This is how the structure looks like for param with key ***"ampm"***

```c
--NSDictionary (response)
----NSDictionary for key forecast
-------NSDictionary for key simpleforecast
---------NSArray for key forecastday
-----------NSDictionary as first array object
-------------NSDictionary for key date
---------------NSString for key ampm
```

### EDIT:

I just found this tool, you might find it helpful :)

[JSON VIEWER](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)

How to use it:

1. Place your request (but change API KEY :))  request into a browser
   `http://api.wunderground.com/api/YOUR_API_KEY/forecast/q/Chicago.json`
2. Copy the API response to the tool's 'Text' page.
3. Go to 'Viewer' page and analize the response.

Comment: Very interesting, and yes your code does return values. The only thing I don't understand is:     id firstPartOfDailyForecast = [forecastday firstObject]; What is firstObject? Is that the first day? Is that a JSON reference? I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: Look at my lastest edit. The NSArray for key "forecastday" contains 4 elements - Each one for different period of day. So i guess, the first one refers to the morning. And `firstObject` is `NSArray` method, it works exactly like `objectAtIndex:0`.

Comment: Bartok, first thanks for taking the time to help me understand this and sharing the JSON Viewer tool. It helped me figure out, I think, which are arrays and which are dictionaries.  [] are arrays (use NSArray) and {} are dictionaries (use NSDictionary).

Comment: You're welcome :) And yes, in this tool [] stands for arrays and {} for dicts.